# Formulário de envio de email - asp clássico

Tags: php, html, asp

Preciso de ajuda com o envio de e-email a partir de um formulário em `html`.

O formulário já está pronto e eu tinha um código `PHP` que fazia este envio, contudo o servidor do cliente não está aceitando o código `PHP` e eu preciso mudá-lo para `ASP`.

Como sou iniciante e até então só havia usado `PHP` estou com dificuldades para transformar o trecho abaixo em um código `ASP`.

```
<?php

$email=$_POST['email'];

$assunto=$_POST['assunto'];

$menssagem=$_POST['texto'];

$Destinatario="exemplo@hotmail.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $_POST["email"] . "<" . $_POST["email"] . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

mail($Destinatario, $assunto, $menssagem, $headers);

header("Location: index.html");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo um exemplo básico de envio de E-mail com o componente [CDOSYS](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp) do asp clássico.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>

<%
'Passo 1: Criar o objeto CDO.Message
Dim objMail 
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

'Passo 2: Configurar o usuário e senha para autenticação SMTP
Dim smtpServer, seuEmail, suaSenha
smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
seuEmail   = "caique.romero@emitente.com.br" 
suaSenha   = "teste@#Teste87761"  

'Passo 3: armazenar o e-mail de quem receberá a mensagem.
enviarEmailPara = "caique.romero@destinatario.com.br"

'Passo 4: Configurar as propriedades do objMail(porta, servidor...)
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = smtpServer
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = seuEmail
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = suaSenha
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

'Passo 5: Atualizar a configuração após definir as propriedades
objMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'Passo 6: Preparar o e-mail
Dim assunto, mensagem
assunto  = "Pesquisa de satisfação"
mensagem = "Olá, essa respota lhe foi útil?</br>"
mensagem = mensagem & " Att., Caique Romero"

objMail.From      = seuEmail'Configuro o emitente
objMail.To        = enviarEmailPara 'Configuro o destinatario
objMail.Subject   = assunto
objMail.htmlBody  = mensagem

'Passo 7: Enviar o e-mail
objMail.Send 

'Passo 8: Limpar o objeto
Set objMail = Nothing 

Response.Write("E-mail enviado com sucesso!!")
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
objArray = Array ("email","assunto","texto")

For Each obj In objArray
    strMessage = strMessage & obj & " : " & Request(obj) & "<br>"
Next

'################### Na época que eu usava asp ###################
'------ utilizava este código para envio -----------

        Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
        Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")  
        objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"  
        objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")= 25  
        objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2  
        objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30 
        objCDOSYSCon.Fields.update  
        Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon  
        objCDOSYSMail.From = email   
        objCDOSYSMail.To = "<" & destinatario & ">"    
        objCDOSYSMail.Subject = assunto   
        objCDOSYSMail.HtmlBody = "<p>" & strMessage & "</p>" 
        objCDOSYSMail.Send  
        Set objCDOSYSMail = Nothing 
        Set objCDOSYSCon = Nothing

'outros scripts de envio de email podem ser vistos no link abaixo
'https://www.baboo.com.br/tutorial/tutorial-software/envio-de-e-mail-com-asp/
'#################################################################


if err.number <> 0 then
    response.write "Problemas no envio, por favor tente mais tarde."
else
    response.redirect("index.html")
end if
```

**CDOSys - Envio autenticado por Email** - [**fonte**](https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/CDOSys_-_Envio_autenticado_por_Email_Locaweb)

```
<% 
objArray = Array ("email","assunto","texto")

For Each obj In objArray
    strMessage = strMessage & obj & " : " & Request.Form(obj) & "<br>"
Next


'CRIA A INSTANCIA COM O OBJETO CDOSYS 
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

'CRIA A INSTANCIA DO OBJETO PARA CONFIGURAÇÃO DO SMTP 
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration") 

'SERVIDOR DE SMTP 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.seudominio" 

'PORTA PARA COMUNICAÇÃO COM O SERVIÇO DE SMTP 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587

'Utilização de SSl 
'objCDOSYSCon.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

'ATIVAR RECURSO DE SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 

'USU?RIO PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "usuario@dominio.com" 

'SENHA DO USUÁRIO PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "senha" 

'TEMPO DE TIMEOUT (EM SEGUNDOS) 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60 

'ATUALIZA A CONFIGURAÇÃO DO CDOSYS PARA ENVIO DO E-MAIL 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields.update 
Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon 

'NOME DO REMETENTE, E-MAIL DO REMETENTE 
objCDOSYSMail.From = "Remetente <usuario@dominio.com>" 

'NOME DO DESINATARIO, E-MAIL DO DESINATÁRIO 
objCDOSYSMail.To = "NOME <destino@dominio.com>"
'objCDOSYSMail.cc = "Copia <copia@dominio.com>" 
'objCDOSYSMail.bcc = "Copia Oculta <copiaoculta@dominio.com>" 


'ASSUNTO DA MENSAGEM 
objCDOSYSMail.Subject = " Envio autenticado - CDOSYS Apps" 

'CONTEUDO DA MENSAGEM 
objCDOSYSMail.TextBody = strMessage 
'PARA ENVIO DA MENSAGEM NO FORMATO HTML, ALTERE O TextBody PARA HtmlBody 

'objCDOSYSMail.HtmlBody = "<html> <head><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html;charset=utf-8""></head><body></body></html>" 

'ENVIA A MENSAGEM 
objCDOSYSMail.Send 

'DESTROI OS OBJETOS 
Set objCDOSYSMail = Nothing 
Set objCDOSYSCon = Nothing 

response.write "Email enviado com sucesso" 

'Response.Redirect "index.html" 
%>
```

Comment: @ÐvÐ, já é tarde, entendo que vc deve estar vendo coisas :D

Comment: Alias, não conhecia request(obj), teria que ser request("obj")

Comment: o request não seria pra pegar um formulário?

Comment: Não tem exemplo funcional, meu servidor não roda asp, mas na época que eu usava asp era isso mesmo

Comment: bom, não quero atrapalhar seu código, mas eu uso request apenas para pegar valor de formulário enviado, tipo request("nome")

Comment: request(variavel) eu não conhecia

Comment: mas se é isso mesmo, eh uma novidade pra mim... só quis dar ênfase no request.form é ultrapassado

Comment: @ÐvÐ esse código na época quem me forneceu foi a galera do servidor

Comment: Eu mexo com asp há 11 anos e só usei request pra pegar post de formulário

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69822/discussion-between-dvd-and-leo-caracciolo).

Answer (score 0):

Pode enviar também pelo componente AspEmail sem que seja necessário autenticação:

```
<%
set AspEmail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
AspEmail.Host = "smtp.dominio.com.br"
AspEmail.FromName = "Nome do remetente"
AspEmail.From = request("email") 'email do remetente
AspEmail.AddReplyTo request("email") 'email do remetente
AspEmail.AddAddress "exemplo@hotmail.com" 'destinatário
AspEmail.Subject = request("assunto")
AspEmail.IsHTML = True 'se a mensagem tiver HTML
AspEmail.Body = request("texto")
AspEmail.Send
response.redirect("index.html")
%>
```

> **Atenção:** provedores de hospedagem bloqueiam o envio caso o email do
>   remetente não pertença ao domínio do site.