# Enviar e-mail com SendGrid e ASP 3

Tags: asp, sendgrid

Como faço para enviar e-mail com SendGrid utilizando ASP 3?

Uso o componente *Persits.MailSender* do asp 3 para enviar os emails. 
Localhost funciona normalmente, mas quando coloco o smtp do sendgrid não vai, dá erro:

> Persits.MailSender.4 erro '800a0017' The password is too long.

Pelo sendblaster a mesma conta, com usuário e senha envia corretante usando o SendGrid.

```
Mailer.Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
Mailer.Username = "usuario"
Mailer.Password = "senha"
```

Comment: Eu nunca utilizei o `SendGrid`, se não for mandatório a sua utilização, nesse link coloquei um exemplo de como enviar e-mail com `asp clássico` : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260824/88202

Comment: @CaiqueRomero desculpe, esqueci desse importante detalhe. Persits.MailSender.4 erro '800a0017'

The password is too long.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero senha longa demais, porém é a senha fornecida pelo sedgrid.

Comment: Pela descrição do erro, a string do campo senha é muito grande, você verificou se a senha está correta e se há um limite máximo por conta do  SendGrid?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero pesquisei bastante no goggle essa informação, não tem nada. Não, os dados da conta estão corretos, no SendBlaster envio com os mesmos dados corretamente. Uso o Persits.MailSender muito mais simples, já uso a muito tempo.

Comment: A solução seria editar a senha no SendGrid, seria simples se ele dispusesse dessa opção. Rs